# ajax jquery in mvc - method return True which is not boolean type

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

In MVC5 I have ajax method in jquery that checking if file exists:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckIfnExists", "Home")',
            data: { idfile: 100 },
            success: function(data) 
            {
                console.log('result: ' + data);
                if(data == 'True')
```

Method in controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool CheckIfnExists(decimal idfile,
{
   return true;
}
```

How to change in jquery 'if' statement to:

```
if(data)
```

from string 'True' to boolean true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()`. Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript value.

```
var str = data.toLowerCase();

if(JSON.parse(str)){

  // your code
}
```

Note:

Using JSON.parse()

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
JSON.parse('{"1": 1, "2": 2}') //Object {1: 1, 2: 2}
```